# For loop, within a loop to carry on incrementing

Tags: laravel, for-loop, laravel-blade, laravel-5.4

The current set up of my view is the following:

A user has 6 input boxes per question that they need to complete. I need each of the input boxes to have a unique ID.

**Current loops:**

```
@foreach($form as $question)
    @foreach($question->questions as $question)                          
        @for ($i = 1; $i < 7; $i++)
            <input type="text" value="1" class="form-control" 
                name="{{ unique ID here }}">
        @endfor
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

I'm unable to use the `id` field of the `$question`, because I need the first input box to start with `1` and increment.

So, for example, within the above set up, it will loop over 7 `$questions` and each of them have 6 input boxes. Essentially, I want it to loop through the first question, increment to 6, loop through the second question, increment to 12 etc..

How can I achieve this please?

Comment: Tried `@for ($i = 1; $i < (7 * count($question->questions)); $i++)` ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply - the above would loop until it gets to 42, within the first loop. Essentially, I want it to loop through the first question, increment to 6, loop through the second question, increment to 12 etc.. It's as if I need a pointer outside of the loop `@foreach($question->questions as $question) `, but I can't figure it out!

Comment: See also https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#the-loop-variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not the best solution, but it should work.

```
@foreach($form as $question)
    @php $uniqueId=0; @endphp
    @foreach($question->questions as $question)                          
        @for ($i = 1; $i < 7; $i++)
            @php $uniqueId++; @endphp
            <input type="text" value="1" class="form-control" 
                name="{{ $uniqueId }}">
        @endfor
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!